# Perturbation of Equations of Motion - Can I Simplify by Using Order 0?

Tags: perturbation-theory

When I have an 0th order equation of motion of the form
$$
0=a(\phi)+\partial_a\partial^a\phi +\partial_\phi V(\phi),
$$
can I use this equation to simplify the first order equation of motion?
Sure, if the first order has a term, containing the 0th order as a factor, it gets cancelled, e.g.
$$
0 = x + y + q*(a(\phi)+\partial_a\partial^a\phi +\partial_\phi V(\phi))
=x +y.
$$

But could I also perturb the 0th order, i.e. $\phi\rightarrow\phi+\delta\phi$ to gain something like

$$
a(\phi)+\partial_a\partial^a\phi +\partial_\phi V(\phi) + \partial_\phi a\delta\phi+\partial_a\partial^a\delta\phi+\partial_\phi^2V\delta\phi=0+\partial_\phi a\delta\phi+\partial_a\partial^a\delta\phi+\partial_\phi^2V\delta\phi
$$
and then say that this last term is also zero? Or would this then be the perturbation of $0$ and therefore not equal to $0$?

I actually think it is the latter, but I don't want to miss a nice opportunity to simplify things and hope someone could validate my thoughts. ;)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: No, it cannot be done as asked.

Perturbing the 0th order, i.e. $\phi\rightarrow\phi+\delta\phi$ gives
$$
a(\phi)+\partial_a\partial^a\phi +\partial_\phi V(\phi) + \partial_\phi a\delta\phi+\partial_a\partial^a\delta\phi+\partial_\phi^2V\delta\phi=0+\partial_\phi a\delta\phi+\partial_a\partial^a\delta\phi+\partial_\phi^2V\delta\phi
=0+\epsilon\neq0
$$
It's like doing
$$
0=x\qquad x\rightarrow x+\delta x=x+1\qquad\nRightarrow0=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

When doing perturbation theory, remember that the algorithm is to solve the nth order equation and then use the solution found there to solve the (n+1)th order equation. So, if we are to use the solution to a previous equation anyway, there's certainly no issue using the equation itself.

However I would like to be very clear that this only applies when doing perturbation theory in which the desired solution $\phi$ is written
$$
\phi(x)=\phi_0(x)+\alpha\phi_1(x)+\cdots
$$
where I am calling $\alpha$ the order tracking parameter for the perturbation. I do not see a you distinguishing between solution orders in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I want to perturb equations of motion. So the final results will be of the form $f_1(\phi)\delta\phi + f_2(\phi)f_3(h)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ contain terms depending on $\phi$ ($\phi$ itself, maybe also squared as well as other functions of $\phi$ and derivatives of those functions wrt to $\phi$) and $f_3$ is a function of metric perturbations (the norm or derivatives of the perturbation of the metric). Now, I would like to express the full perturbation as lean as possible.

Comment: I do not know why you have chosen this specific form or what $\delta\phi$ is intended to mean. Further, my use of $\phi$ is entirely schematic and could easily denote any field, including the components of the metric. The idea of perturbation theory is always to write all fields in an expansion as I have in my answer, put this into the equations of motion, expand order by order, then demand the equations hold order by order.